# Patch video password using the vimeo API

Tags: express, vimeo, vimeo-api

I don't quite understand what's not working here. I try to update the password of a Vimeo video using the API. According tho the docs [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#edit_video) I should be able to do a simple patch request. This is the code I have:

```js
let vimeo = new Vimeo(client_id, client_secret, access_token);

        vimeo.request({
            method: 'PATCH',
            path: '/videos/' + req.body.id,
            query: {
                name: MY_TITLE_STRING,
                description: MY_DESCRIPTION_STRING,
                password: MY_PASSWORD_STRING,
            }
        }, (error, body, statusCode, headers) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                console.log(success);  
            }
        })
```

The name and description get updated no problem, I get no error message but the password stays the same old one. I even tried the "try out" option right beside the docs but even there the password doesn't change. Did anyone ever have that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

It seems like you have to add:

```
                privacy: {
                    view: 'password',
                },
```

Even if the video already has a privacy.view setting of password. Otherwise it won't work.

Hope this helps anybody.